# How to include an extension for SQLite coming with Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, compilation

I have the Anaconda Python distribution installed on Windows and I'd like to add an extension to SQLite used by Python: The `extension-functions.c` file from https://www.sqlite.org/contrib.

The file says I should install MinGW and compile the file first. It asks for an `sqlite3ext.h` which I cannot find in Python.

Where are the files I need to compile this extension for SQLite in Python?
What should be the steps in Windows?

Can I compile this extension on one computer and copy the result to another computer (where I cannot install MinWG)?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/? What about adding this https://github.com/CovenantEyes/sqlcipher-windows/blob/master/StaticLib/inc_priv/sqlite3ext.h into the `include` directory on windows?